# How to avoid getting "possible "null"assignment to a non-nullable entity"

Tags: c#, resharper

Sorry for this awkward example, but I want to keep it as to the point as possible

Lets say, I have parsed a json-file, which gives me the hierarchy below

```
var customers = myObj.SubObj?.CustomerList.EmptyIfNull();
var plusCustomers = customers.Where(...) // Resharper warning
```

myobj cannot be null
SubObject can be null sometimes

I have an extension method

```
IEnumerable<T> EmptyIfNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable) => enumerable ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>();
```

So I expect the plusCustomers-line to be safe(empty list instead of null). But I get a warning

> possible "null"assignment to a non-nullable entity

If I replace the first line with

```
var customers = myObj.SubObj.CustomerList.EmptyIfNull();
```

I get rid of the warning, but that is not correct. How can I convince Resharper that this is ok?...or I'm I mistaken?

Comment: just use the `!` : `var customers = myObj.SubObj?.CustomerList.EmptyIfNull()!;` 
or `customers!.Where(..)`

Comment: aha... that simple, within a minute... I feel stupid... have always been a bit confused by that null-forgiving !, but now I understand a bit more about that as well.,Feel free to paste that into an answer, so Ill set that to "Correct answer" and youll get some SO-cred :) ..., Thanks!

Comment: You were right, I deleted my answer. In this case, because the `SubObj` is nullable and not the `CustomerList` using the `!` is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add brackets:

```
(myObj.SubObj?.CustomerList).EmptyIfNull();
```

The effect of the null chaining (`?.`) is to evaluate the *whole chain* of member accesses to null, if the LHS operand is null,  rather than evaluating just that single member access to null. For example, consider a long chain of member accesses `a.b.c.d.e.f`. If only `a` is nullable, you would only need to write `?` after `a` for this to be safe. It doesn't just evaluate `a?.b` to null if `a` is null, because in that case you'd have to write `?` after every member access for this to be safe, and that's a bit annoying.

So without the brackets, the whole member access is made nullable due to `?.`, regardless of what you call at the end.

By adding brackets, you break up the chain of member accesses, so that `myObj.SubObj?.CustomerList` is of a nullable type, and calling `EmptyIfNull` on that works as expected - returning whatever type `EmptyIfNull` should return.